# Open cart - MySQL query on customer list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb

I am trying to get the customers list who didn't purchase in last 9 months but did in between 9-18 months ago. 
The below query is working fine on the localhost but not on the server which has MariaDB. `SELECT MAX(o.date_modified) GROUP BY o.email` is the query which is causing the error on the server.

Can any one rewrite the statement which can run on MariaDB. My query is

```sql
SELECT 
o.firstname AS FirstName, 
o.lastname AS LastName,  
o.date_modified AS OrderDate, 
o.order_id AS OrderID, 
op.name AS ProductName, 
op.model AS ProductModel, 
p.sku AS ProductSKU 

FROM `store_order` AS o 
JOIN `store_order_product` op 
    ON o.order_id=op.order_id 
JOIN `store_product` AS p 
    ON op.product_id = p.product_id 

WHERE o.order_status_id = '3' 
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH , (SELECT MAX(o.date_modified) GROUP BY o.email), CURDATE( ) ) 
BETWEEN 9 AND 18 
ORDER BY o.date_modified DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
    GROUP BY email
    HAVING MAX(date_modified) > NOW() - 18 MONTH  -- bought in last 18 months
       AND MAX(date_modified) < NOW() -  9 MONTH  -- but not in the last 9
```

That is, no `JOIN` nor subquery is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `correlate` the `sub-query`

```sql
SELECT o.firstname AS FirstName 
       .......
FROM   store_order AS o 
       JOIN store_order_productop 
         ON o.order_id = op.order_id 
       JOIN store_productas p 
         ON op.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE  o.order_status_id = '3' 
       AND Timestampdiff(month, (SELECT Max(o1.date_modified) 
                                 FROM   store_order o1 
                                 WHERE  o1.email = o.email), Curdate()) BETWEEN 9 AND 18 
ORDER  BY o.date_modified DESC
```

Comment: Thanks but its taking endless processing time :(

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
SELECT 
o.firstname AS FirstName, 
o.lastname AS LastName,  
o.date_modified AS OrderDate, 
o.order_id AS OrderID, 
op.name AS ProductName, 
op.model AS ProductModel, 
p.sku AS ProductSKU 

FROM `store_order` AS o 
JOIN `store_order_product` op 
    ON o.order_id=op.order_id 
JOIN `store_product` AS p 
    ON op.product_id = p.product_id 

WHERE o.order_status_id = '3' 
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH , (SELECT MAX(o.date_modified) FROM `store_order` GROUP BY o.email), CURDATE() ) 
BETWEEN 9 AND 18 
ORDER BY o.date_modified DESC
```

MySQL Workbench found error before GROUP BY